# Is there any workaround to use if statement in troposphere templates?

Tags: python, aws-cloudformation, troposphere

I'm trying to add an `if` statement in `add_resource` of troposphere, but I can't. Is there any workaround to do so?

```
s3_bucket = t.add_resource(Bucket(
    "MyBucket",
    if 2>1:
       BucketName="bucket1",
    else:
       BucketName="bucket2",
    CorsConfiguration=CorsConfiguration(
        "CorsConfiguration",
        CorsRules=[CorsRules(
            "AllowOrganization",
            AllowedMethods=["GET"],
            AllowedOrigins=["*"],
        )]
    ),
    Tags=Tags(
        Environment="aa",
    )
))
```

Edit:

I tried to use ternary operators as well, but it didn't work.

```
BucketName= if 2 > 1: "bucket2" else: "bucket3",
```

Comment: @mkrieger1 unfortunately not. I'm basically trying to do this inside of add_resource function parameters. I get this "if" is not definedPylancereportUndefinedVariable 
https://github.com/cloudtools/troposphere/blob/master/troposphere/s3.py#L475

Comment: That's because you didn't use it correctly. `BucketName="bucket1" if 2>1 else "bucket2"` would be the correct syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you want to control the parameters, then you can do your if-statement before the function.

```
if 2 > 1:
    BucketName="bucket1"
else:
    BucketName="bucket2"

s3_bucket = t.add_resource(Bucket(
        "MyBucket",
        BucketName,
        ...
    ))
```

Or you can use ternary operators:

```
s3_bucket = t.add_resource(Bucket(
        "MyBucket",
        "bucket1" if 2 > 1 else "bucket2",
        ...
    ))
```

Note: `2 > 1` will always be true. But I guess you will replace 2 with a variable?

Comment: it didnt work. I get this "if" is not definedPylancereportUndefinedVariable

Comment: Remove your code (past it in a temp txt). Run print('hello world'). If it works, just make a simple if-statement and print: if True: Print('hello world').

Comment: What is a Pylancereport? I don't think the bucket is a Pylancereport. You may have an issue with your settings

Comment: I think this is because of me trying to run if statement inside of add.resource function of parameters. Do you know troposphere? https://github.com/cloudtools/troposphere/blob/master/troposphere/s3.py#L475

Comment: You didn't write the ternary operator right: A if [condition] else B, you did if[condition] A else B. ;)

Comment: you're great! Thanks for catching it!